# how to convert a sql expression into sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, ddl

Can someone convert it to sequelize

```
CREATE TABLE "fundraiserUpdates" (
    "updateId" SERIAL,
    "updateFundraiserId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "updateTitle" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "updateDescription" TEXT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "pk_fundraiserUpdates_updateId_updateFundraiserId"
    PRIMARY KEY ("updateId", "updateFundraiserId"),
  CONSTRAINT "fk_fundraiserUpdates_updateFundraiser_fundRaisers_fundraiserId"
     FOREIGN KEY ("updateFundraiserId") REFERENCES "fundRaisers"("fundraiserId")
);
```

please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an Sequelize instance in `sequelize` variable:

```js
const queryInterface = sequelize.getQueryInterface();
await queryInterface.createTable('fundraiserUpdates', {
  updateId: {
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
  },
  ...
}
```

Look at [QueryInterface](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js%7Equeryinterface) and [Migrations](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/) for further details.